Execute formatted query gives error for insert in postgres function
I'm still new to PostgreSQL, from cypher background. And
I don't get the combination of EXECUTE and INSERT right (in a function body).
INSERT seems to be easy without EXECUTE format(..., like here.
But this:
-- is wrong!
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_meter_val(meter_secondary TEXT, value NUMERIC, vDate TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
RETURNS int LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$body2$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE
    format('INSERT INTO %I', 'meter_values_' || meter_secondary) || '(v, d) VALUES(value, vDate) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id';
END
$body2$;

Trying out with:
SELECT insert_meter_val('test1', 1500.3, '2024-09-26 14:40:00+2');
-- gives error: error: column »value« does not exist"

which makes somehow sense.
Is is possible at all to use EXECUTE for an INSERT statement in a function body? How can I fix the usage of function parameters?
Adding an USING statement just moves the problem, doesn't it? (like USING newvalue, keyvalue in docs).

Reading the docs plpgsql Dynamic SQL would be a good start.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_meter_val(meter_secondary TEXT, value NUMERIC, vDate TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)
RETURNS int LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$body2$
DECLARE
    result_id int;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I (v, d) VALUES ($1, $2) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING RETURNING id'
    , 'meter_values_' || meter_secondary -- save against SQL injection
  )
  INTO result_id
  USING value, vDate; -- your input parameters

  RETURN result_id;
END
$body2$;

However, why do you need this? From experience, I would say you have an issue in your data model.

Thanks! I did not realize that the INTO result_id USING value, vDate; part belongs to the execute statement, not to the command-string (stupid me). The data are very simple (meter data), but I want to use dynamic table names, therefore the effort. I am also working in a NodeRED environment, so no larg(er) application, which accesses the DB. For these reasons I've opted for a little bit of DB programming.
